# Почему происходит медленный полнотекстовый поиск?

Tags: mongodb, mongo

У меня есть коллекция на 7,5 млн строк, записанная в формате JSON:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу производить полнотекстовый поиск по ней.
Для этого я создавал индекс через MongoDB Compass:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или python:

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
client.mydbb.test.create_index([("$**", pymongo.TEXT)])
```

Но когда я делаю запрос:

```
query = {"$text": {"$search": "\"79250614872\""}}

for value in client.mydbb.test.find(query):
  print(value)
```

То время поиска 2-3 минуты.

Это очень плохой результат для меня и я не знаю в чём проблема.
Можно ли что-то с этим сделать?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB может быть не оптимальным для полнотекстового поиска больших коллекций. Возможные причины долгого времени поиска:

- Индекс не был правильно создан или не используется для запроса
- Коллекция не была оптимизирована для полнотекстового поиска

Чтобы решить эту проблему, следует:

- Проверить настройки индекса и убедиться, что он используется для запроса
- Оптимизировать коллекцию для полнотекстового поиска, таким образом, чтобы она могла быстро обрабатывать запросы

Если проблема не решается, можно рассмотреть другие решения, например, Elasticsearch, который специализируется на полнотекстовом поиске и имеет более высокую производительность.

Comment: Хорошо, а Elasticsearch это как отдельная библиотека или она может коммуницировать с mongodb?

Comment: Elasticsearch является отдельной системой для полнотекстового поиска и аналитики. Он может быть использован независимо от MongoDB или в связке с ним.

Comment: Если вы хотите использовать Elasticsearch с MongoDB, можно использовать расширения, такие как Mongo Connector, которые позволяют интегрировать две системы и переносить данные из MongoDB в Elasticsearch. После этого можно использовать Elasticsearch для полнотекстового поиска и аналитики данных, а MongoDB для хранения и управления данными.